# Has anyone seen this graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-colorings

I recently constructed [the graph shown below](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3AClass-2-planar-3-regular.svg) in the process of investigating some problems regarding line graphs and homomorphisms, and then happened to see it on wikipedia. I was wondering if anyone knew of this graph coming up anywhere else.

[image]

If it helps, I was partly inspired by [this paper](http://www.math.nsysu.edu.tw/~zhu/papers/circindex/feb10-04.pdf) which shows that any graph with maximum degree 3 and circular chromatic index 4 must contain $K_4$ with one edge subdivided as a subgraph. Note that the graph in the link above is three copies of $K_4$ with one edge subdivided plus another vertex which is adjacent to the vertices that are subdividing the edges.

Thanks

Comment: The first link you provided mentions that the graphic was created by David Eppstein. It seems that the MO user David Eppstein is the same person. Perhaps he can help you.

Comment: This graph comes up occasionally when planar cubic graphs are investigated, but I don't recall seeing a name for it.

Comment: Joel,

I did contact David Eppstein before I posted here actually. He said that the main property that he knew it for was that it did not have a perfect matching, as opposed to bipartite or 2-connected cubic graphs.

Comment: This graph is a standard example of a 3-regular graph on an even number of vertices which does not have a matching.

Comment: Anton: all 3-regular graphs have an even number of vertices.

Comment: @David: So they do. I find this fact slightly embarrassing.

Comment: Why would having an even number of vertices be an embarrassment to 3-regular graphs?

Comment: @Mariano: it is so, so... common...

Comment: In particular this graph is the *smallest* simple cubic graph with no perfect matching.

Comment: As mentioned in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html , this graph has been implemented in Mathematica as GraphData["NoPerfectMatchingGraph"]. This appears to confirm that the absence of perfect matchings is its most recognized property.

Comment: It deserves a better name than that.

Answer (score 3):

Any connected trivalent graph realises a Schreier coset graph of a subgroup of
the modular group. This yields a transitive permutation group of degree 16 x 3
since we expand each node into an oriented triangle. In the original graph, 
switching the ends of edges & rotating the oriented triangles provides 
generators of order 2 and order 3. Recall PSL(2,Z) = free product C2 * C3.